# How many ways are there to select a pair of cards from a standard deck of cards such that one of the cards is red and the other one is black?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that a pair of cards are selected from a standard deck of 52 cards. And since there are 26 black cards and 26 red cards, so I'm wondering if my thinking is right?

${26!/25! * 26!/25!}$ so it would be ${26*26 = 676}$

Comment: That is correct, if you don't care about the order of the two cards. But if you consider, say, (King of Hearts, Seven of Spades) to be a different selection than (Seven of Spades, King of Hearts), then it's $52\times 26$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TonyK highlighted in the comment, there is another (and I would argue, more natural) interpretation of the question - where the order of draw matters.

Pick the first card - its colour doesn't matter. There are $52$ cards in the deck, so $52$ ways to do this. Then you're restricted to the other colour for the second pick, and there are $26$ such cards, giving you $26$ ways to pick the second card. Hence the number of ways in total is $(52)(26) = 1352$.

If the order of the hand (of two cards) that you've picked doesn't matter - for example, if you having picked the seven of hearts and then the ace of spades is considered the same pick as the ace of spades first then the seven of hearts, then you need to divide the possibilities by $2! = 2$ (to remove the extra possibilities from permuting the two cards in your hand). So the answer is $\frac 12 (52)(26) = 26^2 = 676$, as you originally calculated.

If you want to be complete, you can give both answers with an explanation, and I would do this with an open-ended answer, but if had to choose one interpretation, it would be the former and the answer would be $1352$.

By the way, your computation was a little obscure because you didn't explain *why* you multiplied such and such factorial and divided this and that factorial. This is a common failing in students who just apply formulae blindly, and that leads them to think combinatorics is harder than it really is. It's actually more productive to try to parse the problem with basic common sense and only then apply the math that you need. I'm sure you'll agree the above is easier to understand and explain to others.